# Index lifecycle is not applied into indices

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lifecycle

I created Index lifecycle policy in kibana for my logs.

I added policy to index template via kibana.

But, once my indice is created, lifecycle is not applied.

I can apply lifecycle manualy and it is work.

Can someone help me how to debug or why is not lifecycle applied into my indicies?

In index template - STEP 3 INDEX SETTINSG I can see:

```
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "logs-lc"
    }
  }
}
```

Looks like template has lifecycle, but it is not applied into new indicies.

Why

Answer (score 0):

When you create an index template, you need to provide also the `index.lifecycle.rollover_alias`.
Also, you will need to:

> bootstrap an initial index and designate it as the write index for the
> rollover alias specified in your index template

[Bootstrap the initial time series index with a write index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-alias-bootstrap)

[Create an index template with ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-alias-apply-policy)